Energy Benefits of Using Windows Vacuums to Remove Water That Otherwise Evaporates and Absorbs Energy
I've been using a new window vac and pondering its effect on the temperature in the house - and there seems nothing written about this that I can find. Plainly when the water evaporates energy is absorbed for the transition from liquid water to vapour. However in the evaporation process the water does not first boil, yet energy I am presuming is taken from the room thereby cooling the room. A further consequence would be to cause a reduction in relative humidity of the air that would otherwise be maintined / increased. What is the real energy conserving benefit of say removing 100ml of water from the window in a room that is 10 degrees celcius inside (colder outside external window surface) and how would this be calculated?
